# Factory for deep nested associationw with presence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot

There is a model relationship so `Car` has one `Location` through 2 nested models.

```
class Car
  has_one :owner 
  has_one :relationships, through: :owner
  has_one :location, through: :relationships

  validation :location, presence: true
end
```

I need to create a factory for `Car` so I did this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :car do
    location
  end
end
```

But `create(:car)` raises `HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly` exception:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly:
       Cannot modify association 'Car#location' because it goes through more than one other association.
```

Is there any easy/proper way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can not create `Location` from your factory, because it's a read-only "has one through" association. You need to create `Relationship` record (with `location`) instead. Then your `car` creation will work.

**UPDATE**

To make car factory work as usual `create(:car)` you can define creation of `relationship` with `location` as `before(:create)` callback in `Factory` definition. More information here [Factory Girl - Callbacks](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)

Comment: OK, this should work. But the question was about some kind of solution when it will be possible to use `Car` factory as usual: `create(:car)`

Comment: @freemanoid updated answer with some more thoughts on this specific question